# Отправка MMS без использования startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND))

Tags: android

Я отправляю MMS сообщение с аудио файлом следующим образом:

```
Intent i3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i3.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
i3.putExtra("address", номер телефона);
i3.putExtra("sms_body", текстовое сообщение);
i3.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(прикреплённый аудио файл));
i3.setType("audio/*");
startActivity(i3);
```

А есть способ отправить MMS без использования `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)`? То есть нужно отправить так, чтобы `Activity` отправки не отображалось, а MMS сообщение отправлялось тут же при нажатии на мою кнопку в моём приложении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обойтись без ММС. Например, СМС-ки, они поддерживают бинарные данные. Следовательно, можно отправить аудио файл следующим образом:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendDataMessage(номер телефона, null, 6737, byte[] прикреплённого аудио файла, null, null);
```

Где указал `null` в аргументах - это дополнительные параметры, такие как сканер, проверяющий корректно ли отправлено сообщение, доставлено ли сообщение и так далее. Вот [эта статья](http://codetheory.in/android-sms/) хоть и на английском языке, однако всё расписано чётко, ясно и понятно.